# linker command failed with exit code 1 when running the program

Tags: c++, oop, linker-errors

I am made a BigIntDecimal class that can takes vary big numbers and preform operations on it , now I want to develop another class that is drives from the BigIntDecimal class called "BigReal" it is the same thing as the BigIntDecimal but it should work with decimal numbers

The BigIntDecimal class is working 100%,but when I made the BigReal class and tried to Include it in the main I have this error "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

The BigIntDecimal class header

```
#ifndef BIGDECIMALINT_BIGDECIMALINTCLASS_HPP
#define BIGDECIMALINT_BIGDECIMALINTCLASS_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

class BigDecimalInt{
private:
    string number;
    char sign;
    void setNumber(string num);
    bool checkValidInput(string input);

public:
    bool operator < (const BigDecimalInt& anotherDec);
    bool operator > (const BigDecimalInt& anotherDec);
    bool operator == (const BigDecimalInt anotherDec);
    BigDecimalInt& operator = (BigDecimalInt anotherDec);
    BigDecimalInt operator + (BigDecimalInt number2);
    BigDecimalInt operator - (BigDecimalInt anotherDec);
    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &out, BigDecimalInt num);
    int size();
    int Sign();
    void push_back(char ch);
    void push_front(char ch);

    BigDecimalInt(){}
    BigDecimalInt(string num)
    {
        setNumber(num);
    }
    string getnum(){
        return number;
    }
};

#endif
```

The BigIntDecimal cpp file

```
 #include "BigDecimalIntClass.hpp"

// regex function that checks the validation of the input.
bool BigDecimalInt :: checkValidInput(string input)
{
    regex validInput("[-+]?[0-9]+");
    return regex_match(input, validInput);
}

// constructor that takes a string as an input.
void BigDecimalInt :: setNumber(string num)
{
    bool validNumber = checkValidInput(num);
    if(validNumber)
    {
        number = num;
        if(number[0] == '+')
        {
            number.erase(0,1);
            sign = '+';
        }
        else if (number[0] == '-')
        {
            number.erase(0,1);
            sign = '-';
        }
        else
        {
            sign = '+';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid" << "\n";
        exit(1);
    }
}


// operator < overloading function.
bool BigDecimalInt :: operator < (const BigDecimalInt& anotherDec)
{
    string comp1 = "", comp2 = "";
    long long len1 = number.length(), len2 = anotherDec.number.length();

    while (len1 < len2){
        comp1 += '0';
        len1++;
    }
    while (len2 < len1){
        comp2 += '0';
        len2++;
    }
    comp1 += number;
    comp2 += anotherDec.number;

    if(sign == '-' && anotherDec.sign == '+')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(sign == '+' && anotherDec.sign == '-')
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(sign == '+' && anotherDec.sign == '+')
    {
        return comp1 < comp2;
    }
    else
    {
        return comp1 > comp2;
    }
}

// operator > overloading function.
bool BigDecimalInt :: operator > (const BigDecimalInt &anotherDec)
{
    string comp1 = "", comp2 = "";
    long long len1 = number.length(), len2 = anotherDec.number.length();

    while (len1 < len2){
        comp1 += '0';
        len1++;
    }
    while (len2 < len1){
        comp2 += '0';
        len2++;
    }
    comp1 += number;
    comp2 += anotherDec.number;

    if(sign == '-' && anotherDec.sign == '+')
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(sign == '+' && anotherDec.sign == '-')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(sign == '+' && anotherDec.sign == '+')
    {
        return comp1 > comp2;
    }
    else
    {
        return comp1 < comp2;
    }
}

// operator == overloading function.
bool BigDecimalInt :: operator == (const BigDecimalInt anotherDec)
{
    if (sign == anotherDec.sign && number == anotherDec.number)
    {
        return true;

    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// operator = overloading function.
BigDecimalInt& BigDecimalInt :: operator = (BigDecimalInt anotherDec)
{
    sign = anotherDec.sign;
    number = anotherDec.number;
    return *this;
}

//addition implementation.
string addition(string num1,string num2)
{
    auto it1 = num1.rbegin();
    auto it2 = num2.rbegin();
    string res = "";
    int carry = 0;
    while (it1 != num1.rend())
    {
        int twoDigitsSum;
        carry = 0;
        twoDigitsSum = ((*it1 - '0') + (*it2 - '0'));
        if (twoDigitsSum >= 10)
        {
            carry = 1;
        }
        res = char((twoDigitsSum % 10) + '0') + res;
        *(it1 + 1) = char(((*(it1 + 1) - '0') + carry) + '0');
        it1++;
        it2++;
    }
    if (carry)
    {
        res = char((carry) + '0') + res;
    }
    return res;
}

//subtraction implementation
string subtraction(string num1,string num2){
    deque<long long>d;
    string res;

    for (long long i = num1.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (num1[i] < num2[i])
        {
            num1[i] = char (((num1[i] - '0') + 10) + '0');
            num1[i - 1] = char (((num1[i - 1] - '0') - 1) + '0');
            d.push_front((num1[i] - '0') - (num2[i] - '0'));
        }
        else
        {
            d.push_front((num1[i] - '0') - (num2[i] - '0'));
        }
    }

    for (auto i : d)
    {
        res += to_string(i);
    }
    return res;
}

// // operator + overloading function.
BigDecimalInt BigDecimalInt :: operator + (BigDecimalInt number2)
{
    BigDecimalInt result;
    char signNumber1 = sign, signNumber2 = number2.sign;
    string num1 = number, num2 = number2.number;
    BigDecimalInt number1 = *this;

    while (num1.length() < num2.length()){
        num1 = '0' + num1;
    }
    while (num2.length() < num1.length()){
        num2 = '0' + num2;
    }

    if (signNumber1 == signNumber2){
        result.sign = signNumber1;
        result.number = addition(num1,num2);

    }else{

        if(number1.sign=='-')
        {
            number1.sign = '+';
            result = (number2-number1);
        }
        else{
            number2.sign = '+';
            result = (number1-number2);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// operator - overloading function.
BigDecimalInt BigDecimalInt :: operator - (BigDecimalInt anotherDec)
{
    BigDecimalInt obj;
    deque<long long> d;
    string strmin = "", res = "";
    string num1 = number, num2 = anotherDec.number;
    char sign1 = sign, sign2 = anotherDec.sign;

    if (number.length() > anotherDec.number.length())
    {
        for (long long i = 0; i < number.length() - anotherDec.number.length(); i++)
        {
            strmin += '0';
        }
        strmin += anotherDec.number;
        num2 = strmin;
    }
    else if (number.length() < anotherDec.number.length())
    {
        for (long long i = 0; i < anotherDec.number.length() - number.length(); i++)
        {
            strmin += '0';
        }
        strmin += number;
        num1 = strmin;
    }

    bool ok = false, is_determined = false;
    if (num1 < num2)
    {
        swap(num1, num2);
        swap(sign1, sign2);
        ok = true;
    }

    if (sign1 == sign2 )
    {
        res = subtraction(num1,num2);

        if(sign1=='-')ok = !ok;
    }
    else
    {
        res = addition(num1,num2);
        if(sign == '-')
        {
            obj.sign = '-';
            is_determined = true;
        }
        else
        {
            obj.sign = '+';
            is_determined = true;
        }

    }

    bool right = false;
    for (long long i = 0; i < res.length(); i++)
    {
        if (res[i] != '-' && res[i] != '0')
        {
            right = true;
        }
        if (!right && res[i] == '0')
        {
            res.erase(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }

    if(res.empty()) res = "0";
    if (!is_determined && (ok))
    {
        obj.sign = '-';
    }
    else if(!is_determined)
    {
        obj.sign = '+';
    }

    obj.number=res;
    return obj;
}

// function to return the size of number.
int BigDecimalInt :: size()
{
    int s = number.size();
    return s;
}

// function returns the sign.
int BigDecimalInt :: Sign()
{
    if (sign == '+')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

// function to push a character.
void BigDecimalInt ::push_back(char ch)
{
    number.push_back(ch);
}

// function to push a character in the front.
void BigDecimalInt ::push_front(char ch)
{
    string temp;
    temp = ch + number;
    number = temp;
}

// operator << overloading function.
ostream &operator<< (ostream &out, BigDecimalInt num)
{
    if(num.sign == '+')
    {
        out << num.number ;
    }
    else
    {
        if(num.number == "0")
        {
            out << num.number ;
        }
        else
        {
            out << num.sign << num.number ;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

the new "BigReal" header file:

```
#ifndef BIGREAL_BIGREALCLASS_HPP
#define BIGREAL_BIGREALCLASS_HPP

#include "BigDecimalIntClass.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class BigReal : public BigDecimalInt{
    private:
        BigDecimalInt bPoint;
        BigDecimalInt aPoint;


    public:
        BigReal (double realNumber = 0.0); // Default constructor
        BigReal (string realNumber);
        BigReal (BigDecimalInt bigInteger);
        BigReal (const BigReal& other); // Copy constructor
        BigReal (BigReal&& other); // Move constructor


        BigReal& operator= (BigReal& other); // Assignment operator
        BigReal& operator= (BigReal&& other); // Move assignment
        BigReal operator+ (BigReal& other);
        BigReal operator- (BigReal& other);
        bool operator<  (BigReal anotherReal);
        bool operator>  (BigReal anotherReal);
        bool operator== (BigReal anotherReal);
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, BigReal num); 
        friend istream& operator >> (istream& out, BigReal num);

        int size();
        int Sign();
        void set_aPoint(BigDecimalInt p){aPoint= p;}
        void set_bPoint(BigDecimalInt p){bPoint= p;}
        BigDecimalInt get_aPoint(){return aPoint;}
        BigDecimalInt get_bPoint(){return bPoint;}

};

#endif
```

the "BigReal" cpp file:

```
 #include "BigRealClass.hpp"
 #include "BigDecimalIntClass.hpp"
// #include "BigDecimalIntClass.cpp"

BigReal::BigReal(string realNumber){
    string before,after;
    int z;
    for(int i = 0; i < realNumber.size(); i++){
        if(realNumber[i] == '.') i = z;
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < z; i++){
        before += realNumber[i];
    }
    for(int i = z+1; i < realNumber.size(); i++){
        after += realNumber[i];
    }

    aPoint = after;
    bPoint = before;


}

BigReal::BigReal (const BigReal& other){
    bPoint = other.bPoint;
    aPoint = other.aPoint;
}

BigReal::BigReal (BigReal&& other){
    bPoint = move(other.bPoint);
    aPoint = move(other.aPoint);
}

BigReal& BigReal::operator= (BigReal& other){
    bPoint = other.bPoint;
    aPoint = other.aPoint;
    
    return *this;
}

BigReal& BigReal::operator= (BigReal&& other){
    bPoint = move(other.bPoint);
    aPoint = move(other.aPoint);
    return *this;
}


BigReal BigReal::operator+(BigReal& other)
{
    BigReal result;
    result.aPoint = aPoint + other.aPoint;
    result.bPoint = bPoint + other.bPoint;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: How do you get linker errors when running a program?  Usually, a program needs to pass the linking state before it becomes an executable.  Please paste, as text, the build error messages, verbatim.

Comment: Don't use `using namespace std;`.  There is a `std::size()` function which may cause collisions with your `size()` method.